# Why does Seaborn keep drawing non-existing range value on the x-axis?

Tags: pandas, seaborn

Snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

test = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,5,7,8,10,11,12,15,16,18,20,36,37,39]})
test['range'] = pd.cut(test.value, np.arange(0,45,5)) # generate range
test = test.groupby('range')['value'].count().to_frame().reset_index() # count occurance in each range
test = test[test.value!=0] #filter out rows with value = 0

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10, 1))
sns.barplot(x=test.range, y=test.value)
```

Output:
[image]

If we look at what's in `test`:

```
     range   value
0   (0, 5]      3
1   (5, 10]     3
2   (10, 15]    3
3   (15, 20]    3
7   (35, 40]    3
```

The range `(20,25], (25,30],(30,35]` have already been filtered out, but they still appear in the plot. Why is that? How can I output a plot without empty ranges?

---

P.S. @jezrael 's solution works perfect with the snippet above. I tried it on a real dataset:

Snippet:

```
test['range'] = test['range'].cat.remove_unused_categories()
```

Warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I used the following instead to avoid the warning:

```
test['range'].cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)
```

This is caused by using multiple variables, so be aware:

```
test = blah blah blah
test_df = test[test.value!=0]
test_df['range'] = test_df['range'].cat.remove_unused_categories() # warning!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem `range` column is [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#removing-unused-categories), so categories are not removed by design like in another [operations](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations).

You need [`Series.cat.remove_unused_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html):

```
...
test = test[test.value!=0] #filter out rows with value = 0
print (test['range'])
0      (0, 5]
1     (5, 10]
2    (10, 15]
3    (15, 20]
7    (35, 40]
Name: range, dtype: category
Categories (8, interval[int64]):
[(0, 5] < (5, 10] < (10, 15] < (15, 20] < (20, 25] < (25, 30] < (30, 35] < (35, 40]]

test['range'] = test['range'].cat.remove_unused_categories()
print (test['range'])
0      (0, 5]
1     (5, 10]
2    (10, 15]
3    (15, 20]
7    (35, 40]
Name: range, dtype: category
Categories (5, interval[int64]): 
[(0, 5] < (5, 10] < (10, 15] < (15, 20] < (35, 40]]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,10, 1))
sns.barplot(x=test.range, y=test.value)
```

[image: graph]

EDIT:

You need [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
test_df = test[test.value!=0].copy()
test_df['range'] = test_df['range'].cat.remove_unused_categories() # no warning!
```

If you modify values in `test_df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`test`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: WOW, didn't even know categorical variables are not being removed! Thx @jezrael!

Comment: Do you mind to take a look at another problem that I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263154/how-to-interpret-seaborn-distplots-axes  really appreciate!